# Better code completion in python notebooks

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter

How come python code suggestion is awful in notebooks and spyder? Smetimes it shows classes methods and variables, sometimes not

Answer (score 2):

If you are working locally (running e.g. starting up a Jupyter notebook from a terminal on localhost) code completiong should work just fine - I have never had any problems.

If you are running a Jupyter notebook attached to a Python process in a Docker container, there can be issues with code completion (the two-way communication may need to be activated).

You can try running the following `ipython` "magic command" that makes the interpreter *greedy* - this has worked for me in the past:

```
%config IPCompleter.greedy = True
```

Simply run that in the first Jupyter cell.

Here is a list of all [built-in magic commands](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html).

I am afraid I don't know of any differences in these cases between jupyter notebooks and Spyder.